# Update Text in credit memo email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, creditmemo

app\design\frontend\Theme\name\Magento_Sales\templates\email\creditmemo\items.phtml

Below script showing total related details in refund email template.

```
<tfoot class="order-totals">
 <?= $block->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?>
</tfoot>
```

How can i change text **Grand Total** to **Refund Total**?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this things.

1. Overide `_initTotals()` function of this file

> Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Creditmemo\Totals.php

into your custom extension.

1. Into overided file, add below code at last into above function.

   ```
   public function _initTotals()
   {
   parent::_initTotals();

   $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
   $source = $parent->getSource();

   $this->removeTotal('base_grandtotal');
   if ((double)$this->getSource()->getAdjustmentPositive()) {
       $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
           [
               'code' => 'adjustment_positive',
               'value' => $this->getSource()->getAdjustmentPositive(),
               'label' => __('Adjustment Refund'),
           ]
       );
       $this->addTotal($total);
   }
   if ((double)$this->getSource()->getAdjustmentNegative()) {
       $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
           [
               'code' => 'adjustment_negative',
               'value' => $this->getSource()->getAdjustmentNegative(),
               'label' => __('Adjustment Fee'),
           ]
       );
       $this->addTotal($total);
   }

   $this->removeTotal('grand_total');
   $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
               [
                   'code' => 'grand_total',
                   'field' => 'grand_total',
                   'strong' => true, 
                   'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
                   'label' => __('Refund Total'),
               ]
           );
           $parent->addTotal($total);
   return $this;
   }
   ```

Comment: Now in email template it's showing this message in email body. : We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

Comment: try to check that, in log files, does it show anything?

Comment: not showing any error related to this changes.

Comment: I update answer with entire code of that function. Kindly check.